# Adding product type in prestashop add product page

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Iam new to prestashop ,iam trying to add new product type in addition to  Standard product,Virtual product ,Pack of existing products

Added this in informations.tpl file

```
<
div class="radio">
                <label for="digital_product">
                    <input type="radio" name="type_product" id="digital_product" {if $is_in_pack}disabled="disabled"{/if} value="{Product::PTYPE_DIGITAL}" {if $product_type == Product::PTYPE_DIGITAL}checked="checked"{/if} >
                    {l s='Digital product (services, booking, downloadable products, etc.)'}</label>
            </div>
```

i want to save this in new column is_digital in ps_product table.iam struck here.Please help. Is there any any documentaion for full  working flow of  all classes and functions of prestashop?

Comment: If you want to add a new product type, then you should do that via the shop’s _configuration_ rather than by hacking something into a template file. Make it a category for example.

Comment: where i can see this configuration?

Comment: I meant “configuration” in a general way (as opposed to hacking stuff into templates). If you are unclear about specifics, such as how to create a new category, then please consult the documentation and/or google it.

Comment: i know that.But is there any way to add additional product type from back end?i cant find this option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the core workings of PrestaShop is a HUGE undertaking. You should and must use a module for cases like this.

1. Go to `Hook.php` and find `exec()` function. Use `error_log($hook_name)` to find out which hook are availble when a specific action is performed. For example, when you open product edit page, they may be `FormModifier` hook which you could use to add a radio box for a new product type. But that is just "cosmetics" of adding an new type.
2. You should create a module for modifying PrestaShop. First, try to find if there is a hook available to modify what you need. If there isn't, you will need to override the actual `class/controller`. Overrding is easy, but generally not recommended. Create copies of class/controller files in your module folder: `modules/yourmodule/override/controller/admin/AdminProductCotnroller.php` and only leave functions which you are overrding. Also, try to make if conditional: 
   `if ($iCanModify) { // Modify} else { return parent::method(); }`
3. Track down a product type constant, variable or string (Product::TYPE_STANDARD?) everywhere where it occurs in PS files. You will need to modify/add logic to these places to make you new tyoe work.