# Prestashop 1.7 add type of product

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I was wondering which way is the best to add another 'type' of product in PrestaShop 1.7.
By type, I mean the first select used to define if it's a standard/pack/virtual product.
For now, I found nothing about adding Product Type editable from the Admin panel.
Any clue?

Comment: The answer here is informative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946382/adding-product-type-in-prestashop-add-product-page